# Go to Login Screen after reentering an App from Background Mode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, html, cordova

i only would like to know, if its possible to tell an App "Hey, if the User reopens you from Background-Mode, do not show the Content after the Login-Screen, instead show the login screen". This would be a safety Feature, but i dont know, how to realise this with Cordova.

Some Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use cordova event **resume**. See the cordova [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html) for details

Comment: i didn't know that this is possible. But know it worked fine for me - thank you very much!